# iOS 9 locks mobile wordpress site

Tags: ios, iphone, wordpress

Really hoping you can help me with this strange bug. Ever since updating my phone to iOS 9 my website: https://verweij-juristen.nl seems to be locked. When people visit my site they can't navigate. Also the footer crosses wright through my mobile slider. Even when I turn slider off it still shows and the website still hangs.

It's only on iOS 9 :(

Looking forward to any input :) I'm desperate lol.

Comment: Might be useful if you include which devices you're seeing this happen on, and if possible, a screenshot would really help.

Comment: so far I was only able to test it with my iphone since I don't own an ipad. I will upload the print screen asap

Comment: Are you using `flexbox` somewhere on the page?

Comment: David, honestely I wouldn't know. How can I check if my site is using this?

Answer (score 0):

iOS9 messes up with the viewport meta, you have to tell it to scale your site maximum at initial scale which should be 1.0

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0 ,shrink-to-fit=no"/>
```

This is a meta configuration that works with iOS9

Comment: Thanks so much burimi! Since i'm a complete noob with this. Where do i put this code in my wordpress site so all pages load succesfully?

Comment: @HighSociety I don't know how the actual theme is programmed, but usually it goes on header.php

Comment: Awesome. gonna try to that now. Will keep you posted

Comment: Burimi unfortunately now succes.

Comment: my header.php currently looks like this :    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0 ,shrink-to-fit=no"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

Comment: @HighSociety you have 3 viewport metas, you have to leave only the first one

Comment: also what is weird is even after disabling the revolution slider it still shows the slider on my mobile page?